# Oauth2-proxy failing to sign in after redirecting to oath2 provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, terraform, oauth2-proxy

End goal: `https://auth.wayofthesys.com/oauth2` should redirect to **DigitalOcean** or **GitHub** provider and allow sign in. Currently results in an `"oops something went wrong"` error at **DigitalOcean** and a `"404 page not found"` error at **GitHub**.

Repo is located here, with link to where I believe the **oauth2-proxy** command is failing: https://github.com/autotune/pritunl-k8s-tf-do/blob/6f1afcdce7d9acde640c07f1598dd211f791890e/terraform/cluster_resources.tf#L27

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the helm chart instead of applying manually. Still not sure why it doesn't work outside the helm chart but the problem is resolved for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you share the actual configuration?